# Something's wrong with my gecko

Tags: health, geckos

My Coleonyx gecko dropped her tail yesterday and I thought it could have been my cat or a cricket that scared her.

(9/21)
Today I came home and checked on her and I thought she was dead. Her mouth was open slightly, her legs were all back and straightened.
She felt stiff but then I saw she would blink and she was breathing.

I took her out and held her for a while and I put her in a carrier tank and she squeaked, kind of lunged forward, and I think she had a seizure and a clear liquid and some yellowy white chunky liquid came out pretty fast, so I assumed she just peed and pooped. This would be her first time seizing too.

I've been expecting her to lay an egg soon and I realized later on that she's been having contractions and trying to push. She becomes tired and stops for a while. She's tried again 2 more times and the last time some more liquids came out. But now she's holding her tail up and she pushes for a bit and then her legs start to shake and she's been spreading them far from her body.

She's become pale (I realized later she was shedding) and the egg doesn't look like it's moved at all. 
I don't know what to do.

I can't take her to the vet due to personal circumstances that can't be changed.
And I'm just really worried for her that I've even been depriving myself of sleep so that I can continue to see how she's doing. Any advice would be very useful. Thank you.

Update:
9/23

She seems to be doing better. She's sleeping a lot. I can't touch her at all right now because when I was going to move her back to her tank last night she froze and started seizing.

10/4

I checked her a bit ago and her stomachs smaller and wrinkled. There're no eggs in the tank. A week ago I noticed her jaw is a bit crooked now and today she seems dizzy when walking. I tried to feed her a meal worm and she tried to eat it, but she's not able to catch it or keep it in her mouth.

11/17

She's been doing pretty well now. She laid her eggs last month and hasn't had any more. She's been shedding nicely, but now she won't eat. I would bring her mealworms and she'd be excited, but now she closes her eyes when I show them to her.

11/24

She hasn't opened her eyes for 3 days. She looks around when there's noise but won't open her eyes. She won't eat and now I think I have to try force feeding, since she hasn't tried eating for about 2 weeks. I'm really worried about her. I never wanted to force feed, but I can't let her starve herself.

11/25

I fed her today and she seemed to be doing okay, but now Im worried I did something wrong. I didn't open her mouth. I let her lick from the syringe. She did something like a death roll a night ago after dropping her face into some food I left for her, and now shes been spitting up some clear mucus. She opens her mouth and I've looked inside and nothing seems to be blocking her throat.

Comment: If she's egg bound she will need to be taken to a veterinarian. There's no safe home remedy that will treat egg bound reptiles.

Answer (score 3):

Seizures in geckos are often caused by a lack of calcium. Being that she is due to lay eggs, this could be the reason she is calcium deficient. It pains me to say it, but I have read that once they reach the stage that they are having seizures, death often follows. You can potentially avoid this by having a vet give your gecko a calcium shot. However since this isn't an option for you I would advise a calcium supplement until she passes the eggs and is feeling better. Don't try to handle her right now. Once she is better you should include the calcium supplement in her usual diet as advised on the supplement label.

Comment: Also they sell reptile calcium supplements at pet stores and some Wal-Marts carry them.

Comment: Hi Nid! Would you be able to post some sources to your claim? A few good pointers to writing a good answer can be found here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Seizures in geckos: http://www.reptileboards.com/threads/leopard-gecko-not-eating-and-having-seizures-please-help.65654/         
                                 
Seizures in geckos: https://www.pangeareptile.com/forums/showthread.php?16873-Crested-gecko-having-seizures      
  
  
  
  
  Calcium supplement in reproducing females: https://c.ymcdn.com/sites/members.arav.org/resource/resmgr/Files/Proceedings_2013/56.pdf

Comment: You can also add that "rubber jaw" is a symptom of Metabolic Bone Disease.